# PhpMyAdmin. Как связать одну таблицу с таблицей, где есть JSON

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin, foreign-key

Пробую связать 2 таблицы в phpMyAdmin. С JSON полем не получаются сделать ограничения как с другими типами данных. Видимо надо как-то настроить правильно.[image: изображение ошибки]

Comment: Для установления связи надо чтобы все было одинаково. Одинакоые: тип поля, размер поля, атрибуты поля, кодировка поля, тип таблицы и кодировка таблицы. Если в полях дочерней таблицы уже есть записи, все значения поля, по которому устанавливается связь, должны существовать в родительской таблице или быть равны `NULL`

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите структуру ваших таблиц